# How you increment the version number using Travis CI?

Tags: github, travis-ci

The project that I am working on is a jQuery plugin. I have managed to get Travis CI to build a test project using Gulp/NodeJS successfully. Now I am trying to work out what workflow to use to bump the version number.

In TeamCity and MyGet there is a setting in the CI server to form a version number pattern that auto increments on each build, which can be used by the build script to update versions in the deployment files and to label the Git repo. However, in the free version of Travis CI, there doesn't seem to be an option for versioning at all.

I have read several articles on continuous deployment with Travis CI, [here](http://thewebivore.com/continuously-deploying-free-openshift-site-travis-ci/), [here](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/), and [here](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1749/get-your-ci-on-with-travis-ci), but none of them even broach the topic of versioning. Obviously, the version needs to be changed for the release. So what am I missing here?

Another problem I noted when going through the documentation is that it mentioned that Travis CI is not able to update the GitHub repository. Doesn't that basically mean it won't be able to create a Git tag?

If there is no way to version from Travis CI, then what is the typical workflow for the release process for such a plugin? Is the versioning always done manually? If so, how could there be "continuous deployment"?

Comment: Have you find a solution in the end? I am looking to implement the same, auto increasing the version number on deployment.

Comment: I ended up just keeping it simple and going with [MyGet](https://www.myget.org/). I was unable to enable TravisCI because I am not the owner of the repo and the owner didn't do it. For the version bump, I used [gulp-bump](https://github.com/stevelacy/gulp-bump). Here is my [Gulp script](https://github.com/snikch/jquery.dirtyforms/blob/master/gulpfile.js#L230) that updates the version. Note that gulp-bump supports a manual bump workflow as well as an automated one, but only supports versioning .json files. But you could always use regexes to bump anything else (see my script).

Comment: "_Another problem I noted when going through the documentation is that it mentioned that Travis CI is not able to update the GitHub repository_" well you can do that from within the build manually, but since updating a file imply a new commit, you'll end up with a new build

Comment: @rolebi - My point is that there is no way for the CI server to tag the build with the version number, but in this particular case I ended up creating scripts that update several source files to sync the version number across the project/documentation as well.

Answer (score 7):

Before it starts running the instructions in your `.travis.yml` file, Travis will set a bunch of [environment variables](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Default-Environment-Variables) (in the VM that is building your project) with various bits of information about your build, such as what branch is being built and so on.

You probably want one of these:

- `TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER`: The number of the current build (for example, “4”).
- `TRAVIS_JOB_NUMBER`: The number of the current job (for example, “4.1”).

But it's going to be very difficult to do *anything* sensible if you don't have control of the repository, because you'll need to upload a `.travis.yml` file into the root of your source code folder, otherwise Travis won't know what to do.

Comment: Thanks. I *do* have control of the repository - that is, I am a collaborator and can make commits to it. But I don't have permission to turn on TravisCI. I *do* have permission to enable MyGet so I went with that instead. I am not sure why TravisCI hasn't found a workaround for that, but MyGet did.

Answer (score 7):

Use [bumped](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bumped) for release versioning. When you're satisfied with the changes in master, run:

```
bumped release <major|minor|patch>
```

After you push the changes, either directly or through a release PR, you can check for the presence of new tags in Travis CI and publish the package to the registry automatically.

Answer (score 5):

If you consider that every PR must end up to your enduser without thinking of the impact of such changes, then your version numbers have no meaning.

You don't give your user a way to know if it is a major change that break compatibility or a bug fix. You don't allow him to get update without worrying about backward compatibility.

Currently, the commit id is your version number.

If you want to give meaning to your version numbers then you have to think of the impact of your pull requests on the enduser (http://semver.org/). You have to choose a version number for a specific PR or a group of PR.

So basically, since you have to 'think' of a certain version number for a specific version that you want to deliver, you can't automate this process.

Release/tag creation is the way to go : )

Comment: I do use tag creation, but I want the CI server to be the official source of the version number rather than having to manually run scripts to increment the version and tag the repo on every build. This manual work is both unnecessary and error prone and really defeats the whole purpose of using CI as far as I am concerned. MyGet does everything I want without the headaches and allows me to set it up even though I am not the owner of the GitHub repo, whereas Travis CI does not.

Comment: You make *a lot* of assumptions that often don't hold.  The latest version on a given branch is typically *by definition* what you want users to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by setting up a script that would create a ~/.netrc file to access the repository.  In this file you can specify something like:

```
machine https://github.com/xxx/yyy.git
login <blah>
```

And instead of putting in your credentials, you can pass an github access token.  You can use the `travis encrypt` to register it in the .travis.yml file, and export the variable for your script's use.  From there in your script, you can issue regular git commands such as:

```
git add <some file>
git commit -m "This is $TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER"
git push origin <branch>
```